# Why all the downvotes?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Seven of my answers just got one downvote each, all at just about the same time ("4 hours ago," about 11am Eastern US Time). I only have ten answers out there, so this is a surprising event. Not terribly upsetting; they're just points.

I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this - did someone go after random answers? - or if it's just someone who decided I give lousy answers.

Comment: I bet the anti-targeting voting algorithm will reverse that for you in a little while.

Comment: Anti-targeting algorithm? Cool.

Comment: It should atuomagically reverse by tomorrow. If it doesn't, you can flag one of your answers that received a downvote and request that a mod look into the serial downvoting that occurred.

Answer (score 8):

Most likely, you've been targeted by somebody.  This is called [serial voting](https://writers.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed).  Votes are supposed to be for the *content*, not the *author*.  If a user has targeted you with several votes in short succession, the votes should be reversed by the nightly script that detects and corrects such voting patterns.

If it happens once and gets corrected, well, that's annoying but we shrug and move on.  If you notice it happening repeatedly, even if the episodes are getting corrected, please raise a flag on one of your posts to alert moderators to the problem.  Serial voting is a violation of site rules, so if there is a pattern of it please bring it to our attention.

Comment: Good explanation. Thanks.